# Why laravel creates 3 same records?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

i have this route

```
Route::get('org/add', ['as' => 'org.add', 'uses' => 'OrgController@add']);
Route::post('org/add', ['as' => 'org.add', 'uses' => 'OrgController@create']);
```

this controller method

```
public function add(Org $org)
{
    return view('org.add');
}

public function create(Org $orgModel, Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->all());
    $orgModel->create($request->all());
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Added');
    return redirect()->route('org.index');
}
```

and this template

```
{{ Form::model('Org') }}
{{ Form::text('orgnamefull', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Full org name', 'id' => 'orgnamefull']) }}
{{ Form::button('Go', array('class'=>'btn btn-default', 'type'=>'submit')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Org extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'orgs';
     protected $fillable = ['orgnamefull', 'orgnameshort', 'orginn', 'orgkpp', 'orgaddr', 'orgdirname'];
}
```

After form submit i get 3 same records in database and not know where find to debug.
What could lead to the creation of several records and where to find bug?

Comment: Please post the model code also and check if there is any loop that is being closed after the form or not

Comment: there is no loops, and, as i see, it makes records in other model

Comment: Other model means? Your table name is orgs and 3 values are stored in orgs table right? Or in different table? Post the creatr method in the model too bro

Comment: could you check if `$orgModel` has values before you call `create` ?

Comment: i found solution. it causes by http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/ cors enabled